# API Management node goes offline

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

We are working with the API Management service for Bluemix. When the management node goes offline, are the APIs still available because they are served by the Gateway (DataPower) nodes? We are aware that an option is to have a second management node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Management node goes offline, the APIs are still available for use as they are served by Gateway(Datapower) nodes. However, you will not be able to publish new APIs or manage the existing APIs. The analytics records will be batched for a period of time and will be ready to be passed to the Management node when it returns. Depending on the length of the Management node outage and the volume of API calls, it is possible that the buffer might overrun and the oldest analytics records will begin to be discarded.